# Running a Chrome Native Client (NaCL) plugin without Chrome

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, text-to-speech

I'm in charge of developing an application that uses Text-to-Speech functions. I was previously using Google's undocumented tts API. That API recently had some changes to it that adds a captcha if it detects automated usage. Due to the way the application is deployed, solving that captcha is not possible. I found this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/us-english-female-text-to/pkidpnnapnfgjhfhkpmjpbckkbaodldb?hl=en-US which seems to be an older version of what the undocumented google tts API uses, since there's a few differences and it sounds slightly more robotic. I also have been unable to find the source code to that PATTS engine that the extension uses unfortunately.

I would love to use that extension in my application, and therefore i'm looking for a way to use that in my application without using Chrome. The extension itself is comprised of a .nexe file, and the voice data itself.

Basically i'm looking for a way to host that .nexe file in my application.

Comment: What's wrong with just using [`chrome.tts` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tts)?

Answer (score 0):

Running a Chrome App is not really running "without" Chrome.

(P)NaCl is fully supported, however NaCl apps [need to be distributed from Web Store](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#non-portable-native-client) for Chrome to allow running the module. The above link is also a lengthy guide to packaging NaCl modules with the app.

That said, who says that taking a compiled blob from an extension (what is the license for the extension, by the way) is a good idea?

---

There's a native alternative in Chrome API, [`chrome.tts` API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tts). From what I see in the docs, there are no built-in providers on Linux though.